# flash as3 timeline animation storing value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, shared-objects

I set a value on frame 20 of my animation

```
var final_answer = hundreds.text+tens.text+units.text;
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("/");
```

I want to access this on frame 40 but I get the following error

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 210, Line 5 1120: Access of undefined property mySharedObject.

```
I have also tried to use a normal variable - is there anyway to store a variable in what is effectively a cookie between frames?
```

Comment: please see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4028473/1263701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use document class but if you don't want and handle all in the first frame you  can use `addFrameScript`

```
addFrameScript(4,onFrame5);

function onFrame5():void{
    trace('current frame is 5');
}
```