# as3 Child won't be removed

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, so I have a button when clicked goes to frame 15. If xpsafety is 0 I want a child to be created and xpsafety to be set to 1. So if the button is clicked again it wont display the child and do the calculation

Fame 10:

```
var xpsafety:int = 0;
var xpclip:MovieClip = new xp();

RememberButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoToRemember); 


function GoToRemember(evt:MouseEvent):void { 
gotoAndPlay(15, "Scene 1");
if (xpsafety == 0) {
    addChild(xpclip);
    xpclip.x=41;
    xpclip.y=835;
    calculateExp(8);
    xpsafety = xpsafety +1;
}


}
```

Frame 15:

```
stop();


    BackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoBackSafety); 

    function GoBackSafety(evt:MouseEvent):void { 
        gotoAndPlay(10, "Scene 1");
        removeChild(xpclip);
        }
```

The error I get is this: ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

I don't understand what it means, any tips? Please and thank you.

Other issue but it's probably related, despite xpsafety being not equal to 0 the function still goes off ( I know because calculateExp(8) happens.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All I needed to do was put my variable inside the if statement on frame 15.....as below:

```
stop();

BackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoBackSafety); 

function GoBackSafety(evt:MouseEvent):void { 
    gotoAndPlay(10, "Scene 1");

    }

var xpclip:MovieClip = new xp();
if (xpsafety==0) {
    var xpsafety:int = 0;
    addChild(xpclip);
    xpclip.x=41;
    xpclip.y=835;
    calculateExp(8);
    xpsafety = xpsafety +1;
    trace(xpsafety);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I did any frame scripting, as it soon gets cumbersome and hard to manage. See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028250/passing-a-variable-between-frames-with-actionscript-3).

On the `xpsaftey` issue, when you go back to frame 10 the whole script is run again and the variable `xpsaftey` is being redefined with the default value of `0`. You would need to place the declaration `var xpsafety:int` on an earlier frame in order to prevent this.

Your second example with `xpsaftey` inside the for loop is just confusing things further as you are redefining it again within the scope of the if statement. I suggest having a general read about variable [scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like :

```
xpclip.parent.removeChild(xpclip);
```

Comment: I get this error:TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. When playing through.

Comment: That mean your xpclip object it's null... You can check that before removing, maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access your `xpclip` variable from inside a listener, try this.

```
var mc:MovieClip = (root as MovieClip).xpchild;
(root as MovieClip).removeChild(mc);
```

If this still doesn't work, check if `mc` isn't null.

Comment: I have another flash project where I used the same variable inside a listener and it worked...I don't quite understand what I need to do with the two lines of code you put up.